# What grows beneath Lapageria?

Tags: plant-recommendations, ground-cover

*Lapageria*, a forest native of southern Chile, prefers acidic, organic, damp, shaded, cool, well-drained soil.

I wonder if there's a suitable native groundcover to match. What smaller plants grow around *Lapageria* in the wild?

Answer (score 1):

Probably nothing much grew beneath it in its native habitat - it grows in forests and is a twining climber, so it will likely scramble up trees and head for the light. It prefers partial to full shade anyway, so best planted where that can be provided.

If you want to know what to plant in front of it, azaleas spring to mind, provided you're not in USDA zone 10 or above.

Comment: I can only imagine that the Chilean forest floor has other plants on it.

Comment: Possibly - if its deciduous forest, then in spring there may be a carpet of plants